# How to create multi-ring buffers automatically in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a tool or plugin for QGIS that allows for multi-ring buffers.  I've found a post about doing multiple buffers one by one, but was hoping there was a way to do this all in one place.  I know in ArcMap that you can set the number of buffers you want and distance, so just hoping there's something out there in QGIS to accomplish this.